# Commuting inverse metric with covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor

In a book I'm reading the authors appear to frequently commute the coefficients of the inverse metric with covariant derivatives. Specifically they write things like $$g^{ij}\nabla_lfg_{jk}=\nabla_lf\delta_k^i$$ where $f$ is a function. I can't work out how '$\nabla_l$' is defined which would allow one to make the above manipulation. $g^{ij}\nabla_lfg_{jk}$ doesn't seem to be defined as $g^{ij}\nabla_l(fg_{jk})$ or as $g^{ij}(\nabla_lfg)_{jk}$ but these are the two most obvious definitions. Would anyone else have a clue as to what $g^{ij}\nabla_lfg_{jk}$ actually means?

Comment: Forgetting the $g^{ij}$ at the front for a moment, do you know what is meant by $\nabla_l g_{jk}$?

Comment: @user375366: given your edit, the book seems to use the convention that $\nabla_lfg_{jk}$ means $(\nabla_lf)g_{jk}$, not $\nabla_l(fg_{jk})$, ie the identity is trivial (otherwise, there would be a term $fg_{jk}\nabla_lg^{ij}$ missing)

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which book?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the connection is compatible with the metric: the connection is chosen to have
$$
\nabla_i g_{jk}=0.
$$
This means that you can write $\nabla_{i}fg_{jk}$ without ambiguity, as it is clearly acting only on $f$ (as the action on the metric gives 0). So, it is sufficient to get the metric out of the derivative and make the trivial contraption to get the identity.